# Mixed Authentication Mode ASP.NET - Form ticket not sticking

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, authentication, mixed-mode

I am having trouble with mixed authentication in my asp.net application. My application is set for Forms Authentication with a single location form using Integrated Authentication. The integrated authentication portion seems to be working as expected. I'm able to identify the user, extract the roles and create the FormsAuthentication ticket but the authentication is not reconized when I redirect to my default.aspx. It simply kicks me back to the Integrated Authentication page.

LOGIN.aspx (used for Forms Authentication)

```
<asp:Login ID = "Login1" runat = "server" OnAuthenticate= "ValidateUser" TitleText=""></asp:Login>
```

Login.aspx.vb (Code Behind Forms Authentication)

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Web.Security
Partial Class Login_Login
   Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
   Protected Sub ValidateUser(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
      Dim intUserID As Integer = 0
      Dim strRoles As String = String.Empty
      Dim AdminConn As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("AdminConnectionString").ConnectionString
      Using conn As New SqlConnection(AdminConn)
         Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Validate_User")
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Login1.UserName)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Login1.Password)
            cmd.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()
            Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            Do While reader.Read()
               intUserID = Convert.ToInt32(reader("UserId"))
               strRoles += reader(1).ToString() & ","
            Loop
            conn.Close()
         End Using
         Select Case intUserID
            Case -1
               Login1.FailureText = "Username and/or password is incorrect."
            Case -2
               Login1.FailureText = "Account is not enabled."
            Case Else
               Dim ticket As New FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, Login1.UserName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2880), Login1.RememberMeSet, strRoles, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath)
               Dim hash As String = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket)
               Dim cookie As New HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hash)
               If ticket.IsPersistent Then
                  cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration
               End If
               Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)
               Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(Login1.UserName, Login1.RememberMeSet))
         End Select
      End Using
   End Sub

   Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
      Dim UserName As String = Session("AuthUser")
      Dim UserRoles As String = Session("UserRoles")
      If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
         If Me.Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
            Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx")
         End If
      End If
   End Sub
End Class
```

Global.asax (Used for Forms Authentication)

```
Sub Application_AuthenticateRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
   If HttpContext.Current.User IsNot Nothing Then
      If HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
         If TypeOf HttpContext.Current.User.Identity Is FormsIdentity Then
            Dim id As FormsIdentity = DirectCast(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity, FormsIdentity)
            Dim ticket As FormsAuthenticationTicket = id.Ticket
            Dim userData As String = ticket.UserData
            Dim roles As String() = userData.Split(","c)
            HttpContext.Current.User = New GenericPrincipal(id, roles)
         End If
      End If
    End If
End Sub
```

WINLOGIN.aspx.vb (Code Behind Windows Authentication)

```
Imports System
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Security
Partial Class WinLogin
   Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
   Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
      Dim redirectUrl As String = "~/Default.aspx
      Dim username As String = Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")
      Dim roles1() As String = Roles.GetRolesForUser(username)
      If (Login(username, String.Join(",", roles1))) Then
         Response.Redirect(redirectUrl)
      End If
      If (Page.IsPostBack) Then
         If (Response.StatusCode = 401) Then
            Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx")
         End If
      End If
   End Sub

    Private Function Login(strUser As String, strRole As String) As Boolean
      If (strRole > "") Then
         Dim ticket As FormsAuthenticationTicket = New FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, strUser, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddYears(1), False, strRole)
         Dim strEncryptedTicket As String = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket)
         Dim cookie As HttpCookie = New HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, strEncryptedTicket)
         Context.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)
         Return True
      End If
      Return False
    End Function
End Class
```

Web.Config

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="20480" />
      <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
      <customErrors mode="Off" />
      <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
      <authentication mode="Forms">
         <forms cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" loginUrl="~/WinLogin.aspx" name=".ASPXAUTH" path="/" protection="All" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="10080"/>
      </authentication>
      <authorization>
         <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
   </system.web>
   <location path="Login.aspx">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
      <system.webServer>
         <security>
            <authentication>
               <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true"/>
               <windowsAuthentication enabled="false"/>
            </authentication>
         </security>
      </system.webServer>
   </location>
   <location path="WinLogin.aspx">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
            <allow users="*"/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
      <system.webServer>
         <security>
            <authentication>
               <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false"/>
               <windowsAuthentication enabled="true"/>
            </authentication>
         </security>
      </system.webServer>
   </location>
   <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```